# What is "AWS Simple Query Service"?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have found this "AWS Simple Query Service" into a quiz site question.

```
Mr. A is an architect and he has developed an application which is required to send the data to a NoSQL database.
Mr. A now wants to decouple the data sending such that the application keeps processing and sending data but does not
wait for an acknowledgement of DB. Which of the below mentioned applications helps in this scenario?
1. AWS Simple Query Service
2. AWS Simple Queue Service
3. AWS Simple Workflow
4. AWS Simple Notification Service
```

After that searched on the google about this service.
But couldn't find any helpful explanation. Also not into AWS Documentation site.
(It might be that I have missed any link on the search result)

Is there anyone could help me to know about this service?

[If this question is a complete duplicate, then please share the link. It would be highly appreciated.]

Thanks.

Comment: Probably should be Amazon Simple Queue Service

Comment: I have added the question into details.
What should be the answer?

Comment: Its 2. But SO is not the place for AWS cert questions. This is better place https://old.reddit.com/r/AWSCertifications/

Comment: Good, I have answered the same.
But that site says that its wrong answer.

[I will use your suggested link for future]

Answer (score 3):

There is no AWS service called "Simple Query Service". You are looking at a 'distractor'.

When multiple choice exams are created, one of the techniques used when creating a set of possible answers is to add plausible, but incorrect options. These are called distractors. In this case, 'Simple Query Service' seems plausible (it *sounds* like a real AWS service), but it is an incorrect answer, and some poorly-prepared or less-knowledgeable exam-takers will choose it, to their cost.

Answer (score 2):

This sample question is **not reflective of an actual AWS exam question**.

Official AWS exam questions will also offer plausible options, without inventing fictitious services (such as Amazon Query Service). The exams are not a test of your memorization of service names. Rather, they are a test of whether you know how to apply services appropriate to requirements.

Often, several answers will be 'correct', but the question will ask for an answer that is, for example, "the most cost-effective" or "the most secure". In these situations, you must select the answer that most fits that requirement.

Also, only the AWS Cloud Practitioner exam will ask a question where the answer is merely a service name. All other exams (Associate, Professional, Specialty) will present scenarios where the answers involve steps and decisions. This tests your ability to *apply* your knowledge rather than just recollect information.

**Bottom line:** The exam question is **not representative of a true AWS exam question**. Find a better source of practice questions.